# How to create an Arraylist with an object inside a class in java

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

The exercise is to have a class named Tenant that will be used to store values of tenants for an apartment. In the main class Prog2 I am trying to create an ArrayList that can hold 4 different values, all regarding the tenant class, which are - the tenant's name, apartment number, initial first payment, and monthly payment. I want to be able to print these values out in separate lines that will provide all 4 pieces of information per tenant - followed by a blank line, and then the same 4 pieces of information for another tenant if there is another one. I can get the program to prompt the questions correctly, but then all I get are nulls and 0's printed out (see below at comment). I appreciate all the help - I'm not the best at this.

```
// this class is the tenant class that passes all the tenant's 
information

public class Tenant { 
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String aptNumber;
    private double yearlyRent;
    private String fullName;
    private double firstPayment;
    private double monthlyPayment;

public Tenant(String name, String aptNum, double fPayment, double 
                                                    mPayment){
    name = fullName;
    aptNum = aptNumber;
    fPayment = firstPayment;
    mPayment= monthlyPayment;
}
public Tenant() {

}


public void setFirstName(String name) {
    firstName = name;
}
public void setLastName(String lName) {
    lastName= lName;
}
public void setAptNumber(String apt) {
    aptNumber = apt;
}
public void setRent(double rent) {
    yearlyRent = rent; 
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public String getAptNumber() {
    return aptNumber;
}
public double getRent() {
    return yearlyRent;
}
public double getFirstPayment() {
    double monthlyRent = yearlyRent/12;
    firstPayment = monthlyRent * 3;
    return firstPayment;
}
public double getmonthlyPayment() {
    double firstAndLast = yearlyRent/12;
    monthlyPayment = (yearlyRent - firstAndLast)/11;
    return monthlyPayment;
}
public String getFullName(){
    fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    return fullName;
}

}



// The below class contains the main method 





public class Prog2 {
    public static double getDouble(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Enter yearly rent:");
        while (!scan.hasNextDouble()) {
           scan.next();
           System.out.println("Error: please enter a numeric 
           value");
        }
        return scan.nextDouble();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tenant tnt = new Tenant();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of tenenats:");
    int numTenants = scan.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Tenant> list = new ArrayList<Tenant>();

    for (int i = 0; i<numTenants; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter first name:");
        tnt.setFirstName(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Enter last name:");
        tnt.setLastName(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Enter apt number:");
        tnt.setAptNumber(scan.next());
        tnt.setRent(getDouble(scan));
        list.add(new Tenant(tnt.getFullName(), tnt.getAptNumber(), 
        tnt.getFirstPayment(), tnt.getmonthlyPayment()));             
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getFullName());
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getAptNumber());
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getFirstPayment());
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getmonthlyPayment());
        System.out.println();
    }

}

}
// this prints out: 
null null
null
0.0
0.0

null null
null
0.0
0.0
```

Comment: Your constructor assignments are backwards.

Comment: This seems like a class homework that you try us to do... I hope I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the first constructor in the `Tenant` class. Remember that the `=` operator assigns the value of the right operand to the variable in the left operand. In your case the code should look like this:

```
public Tenant(
        String name, 
        String aptNum, 
        double fPayment, 
        double mPayment)
{
    fullName = name;
    aptNumber = aptNum;
    firstPayment = fPayment;
    monthlyPayment = mPayment;
}
```

What I typically do with constructors is name the parameters after the field, then on the left side of the field assignments use `this` to refer to the field as opposed to the parameter. This ends up looking much clearer:

```
public Tenant(
        String fullName, 
        String aptNumber, 
        double firstPayment, 
        double monthlyPayment)
{
    this.fullName = fullname;
    this.aptNumber = aptNumber;
    this.firstPayment = firstPayment;
    this.monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment;
}
```

`this` can be tricky to use but this is an example where it can clear things up.

Comment: Another useful trick is to make the parameters final - because we shouldn't be updating their values in the constructor. This would have caused syntax errors in the code that would have indicated we were doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Many things are wrong with your code .

1. Constructor of

   public Tenant(String name, String aptNum, double fPayment, double 
                                                       mPayment){
       name = fullName;
       aptNum = aptNumber;
       fPayment = firstPayment;
       mPayment= monthlyPayment;
   }

here your not just assigning null values to your function parameeters, instead of assigning values to your class fields from function parameters.

Also, when you are calling function getFullName() , it will return null as firstName and lastName fields are not initialized.

So, you need to modify your constructor to -

```
public Tenant(String firstNamename, String lastName, String aptNum, double fPayment, double
                                                    mPayment){
    this.firstName = firstNamename;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.aptNumber = aptNum;
    this.firstPayment = fPayment;
    this.monthlyPayment = mPayment;
    this.fullName = getFullName();
}
```

also in for loop , you need to change

```
list.add(new Tenant(tnt.getFullName(), tnt.getAptNumber(), 
        tnt.getFirstPayment(), tnt.getmonthlyPayment()));
```

to -

```
list.add(new Tenant(tnt.getFirstName(),tnt.getLastName(), tnt.getAptNumber(),
        tnt.getFirstPayment(), tnt.getmonthlyPayment()));
```